# How can I append a # in front of each line of a block of text?

Tags: text-processing, xml

This is part of my PHP Myadmin's configuration file:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
```

I want to add `#` in front of each line starting from the first `<Directory>` and until `</Directory>`. How can I do this?

Comment: use vim, line-select (`shift+v`) the needed lines, then `:<>s/^/#/`

Comment: No line contains <Directory>

Comment: @Mikhail Krutov: It said: E488: Trailing characters.

Comment: @123: Sorry, i meant the line start with <Directory, not <Directory>

Comment: TheOne, Also, `sed` variant:


    `sed -e '/match_a/,/match_b/{s/^/#/}' < tst.xml` where match_a and match_b are regexs for needed lines.

Comment: For Vim, need to fix myself: `:'<,'>s/` actually. But '<,'> should be inputed automatically when you enter command w/ some selection (shift-v bit)

Comment: In case of sed command, if my file has too many <Directory tag, it would add # into every <Directory which is not the thing i want.
In case of vim, i didn't know how to select all the lines i want. Of course, i drag my mouse to take all the lines, but after press Shift+v, just the first line of file get selected.

Comment: Slightly easier in vim, use Ctrl+V to highlight the block, then `I# [Esc]`.

Comment: As in `sed '/^<Directory .*\/phpMyAdmin\/>/,/^<\/Directory>/s/^/#/' some.conf` ... ?

Answer (score 3):

With vim there is more than one way to do it:

### 1 - Visual selection

A more detailed explanation of  Mikhail Krutov comment about visual selection:

- `/Directory` to find the first match
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (visual mode)
- `/Directory>` to select all(select until find `Directory>`

  - You can also hit `}` twice to select 2 paragraphs instead of using the search.
- `:'<,'>s/^/#/g` to replace all "start of line characters" with #

  - Vim will probably autocomplete `:'<,'>` when you type `:`, since it knows that you want to do something with your selection.

### 2 - Visual Block selection

As comented by DopeGhoti and  lgeorget:

- Hit <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> for visual block selection
- Hit `}` twice
- Press `I#` and hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>

### 3 - Macro

Another way is using macros. The only caveat is that you need to know how many times you have to repeat a macro after recording it(`set nu` is your friend on helping mentally count lines):

- `qq` - Start recording macro named q
- `I#` - Insert at the start of the line, the character `#`. Hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> to leave insert mode
- Press `jq` to go down one line and stop recording
- Press `17@q` to execute this macro 17 times.

Comment: Or (perhaps more simply) the proposition of @DopeGhoti : Ctrl-V and then `I#<Esc>` to insert `#` in each line.

Comment: And then, you have to repeat EIGHTEEN TIMES using the dot operator. Not always simple means smart

Comment: Hmm no. It will modify each line in the selection once you hit <Esc>.

Comment: Ah, ok. Got it. I didn't realized that "selecting all the block" was implicit so, i it appeared that you selected only the current line. Sorry

Comment: No problem. It's one of the command I use all the times in vim. Very convenient!

Comment: I use visual selection for the same thing. :) Comenting dhcp fixed addresses is a lot easier this way

Answer (score 2):

With perl, it's as easy as:

```
perl -pe 'if ((/<Directory/ && !$done) ... /<\/Directory/) { $done = true; s/^/#/; }' < config_file
```

The trick is the three-dots operators (the two-dots works also as long as `<Directory>` and `</Directory>` are not in the same line).

- `/<Directory/ ... /<\/Directory/` matches all line between these two regexps.
- `/<Directory/ && !$done` with `$done = true;` in the block (`$done` is initially false by default) ensures that only the first `<Directory>` block is matched.
- `-pe` reads the standard input line by line and output `$_` after executing the block of code.
- `s/^/#/` modifies each line matched to prepend `#`.